# Incorrect reading on laptop battery

Tags: battery, battery-life, dell-xps

Since last 3-4 days, my laptop's (Dell XPS 9370) battery is behaving quite erratically.

I use my laptop mostly plugged in during the day, so the battery is charged to 100% at the end of the day. If I take the charger out at any point, it lasts for a couple of hours at the least.

But if I switch it off with 100% battery, and then power it on after an hour, then the laptop thinks the battery is in single digits (6-7%), and warns me that it's about to turn off soon (and it does).

If, however, I manage to connect my charger before that happens, then it quickly charges to 100% before it switches off, and I can again use it for a couple of hours before it runs out.

I think there's something off with the battery reading especially after a fresh reboot. I can't tell what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should not leave your laptop plugged in charging to 100%.  The commonly used value for being constantly plugged in is 80%.  Lenovo and Dell both recommend this. I use the Battery Threshold system on my two Lenovo laptops and they stay plugged in and use a maximum of 80%

Battery Health on my X1 is excellent (battery is 16 months old). Battery Health on my X230 is about half (battery is 4 years old).

All batteries wear out from age more than from the charging threshold used. Try the steps to recalibrate your battery and see if it works normally. Possibly it needs to be replaced.

**You need to do two things:**

**1. Reset (recalibrate) the battery.** Hopefully this step will cause your battery to show correct readings.

https://www.ultrabookreview.com/20942-calibrate-laptops-battery-fix-inaccurate-wear-info/

Here is a summary of the steps:

> Step 1: First, you will need to let your laptop charge to its “full”
> capacity. OEMs like Dell and Lenovo allow the user to set
> charging-thresholds on the battery in order to preserve the battery
> health (this is a very good practice that I encourage all OEMs to
> follow). Thus, to charge the laptop fully, you’ll need to find that
> setting and set your charging threshold temporarily to 100%. On XPS
> machines, this is done through Dell Power Manager or the BIOS.
>
> You’ll need to set the charging behavior to “Standard” or change the
> slider manually to 100% to complete the first step. Once this is done,
> make sure your laptop is plugged-in and allow it to charge completely.
>
> Step 2: Next, you need to let the battery completely discharge until
> forced shut-off (not just hibernation). There are a few ways to do
> this, but my favourite method is the simplest: Restart the laptop in
> BIOS mode, then go out of the house for the day. With this method, you
> don’t need to worry about the laptop going to sleep or hibernating as
> these features are not enabled when viewing the BIOS. Additionally,
> power-saving states are not enabled for the CPU when in the BIOS
> either, meaning the laptop will run down significantly faster than it
> would in Windows under normal usage.
>
> You could also use the laptop normally and let it run down until it
> automatically hibernates, then leave it in BIOS as described above as
> well. This requires your turn off all of the sleep and hibernation
> timers in the Power Options control panel first, however.
>
> Step 3: WAIT. Do not immediately charge the laptop; be sure the laptop
> has been sitting cool and unplugged for 3-5 hours before the next
> step. Failing to perform this step can result in making your reported
> battery wear worse.
>
> Step 4: Plug the laptop in and let it charge to maximum uninterrupted.
> You should be able to use the laptop in Windows at this point, but I
> let it charge in BIOS out of superstition. When you generate your
> battery report again, you should (hopefully) see a much higher rated
> capacity for your new battery.
>
> Conclusion That’s it! Using this method I was able to reduce my 9575
> reporting 14% wear down to 4%, my 9570 reporting 10% down to 3.8%, and
> my 9370 reporting 8% wear down to 4%, and I hope it fixes the problem
> for you simply as well. As always, try to practice good battery care
> to prolong their lives: Keep them cool, don’t run them dry, and don’t
> charge them to maximum often. If you are interested in reading more
> about safety and care for Li-Ion batteries, you can check out this
> guide for further reading.

**2. Set the threshold to 80%**

[Method to set threshold](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-ca/dcpm2.1/userguide_dell-v1/creating-a-custom-battery-setting?guid=guid-773c144b-01aa-44fc-a37f-969e00906d69&lang=en-us)

> Go to the Battery Setting page, and then click Custom. Under Start
> Charging, move the slider to the percentage threshold at which the
> battery begins charging, or enter a number in the text box. For
> example, entering 60 causes the battery to start charging when it
> depletes to 60 percent of the total available charge. Under Stop
> Charging, move the slider to the percentage threshold at which the
> battery stops charging, or enter a number in the text box.

Enter 80 in this box to set the Threshold to 80%

This setting allows you to run the laptop plugged in all the time.